# Magento 2 - How to create a custom select field in registration form and store it in database table?

Tags: magento2, database-schema

I want to create a custom select field of select a course in registration form in which i have  5 options and when user click on create account its value should store in a course column in customer_entity table in magento 2 how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create UpgradeSchema file to add column in table

```
<?php
namespace Companyname\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
    class UpgradeSchema implements  UpgradeSchemaInterface
    {
        public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
                                ModuleContextInterface $context){
            $setup->startSetup();
            
            if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2') < 0) {

                // Get module table
                $tableName = $setup->getTable('customer_entity');

                // Check if the table already exists
                if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
            
                $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('customer_entity '),
                'course_name',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'comment' => 'Course Name'
                ]
            );
            }
            $setup->endSetup();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Then Run Commands:
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush

After that you have to get data in controller directory and save it to the custom column you created.

Comment: how to get data in controller directory

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 uses Data scripts to add attributes. In folder Vendor/Module/Setup/Patch/Data add a .php file (eg: AddCustomerAttributes)

The following will add a customer attribute with options to the dropdown. After adding this bin/magento setup:upgrade command is required.

There will be an entry added to patch_list datatable, if the script file was executed correctly and also the attributes in the eav attribute table of course.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class AddCustomerAttributes implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    protected $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    protected $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * AddCustomerPhoneNumberAttribute constructor.
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        /** attribute_2 */
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'attribute_2',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Attribute Two',
                'input' => 'select',
                'source' => 'Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Options',
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'position' => 1000,
                'default' => 0,
                'system' => 0
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'attribute_2'
        );

        $attribute->addData(
            [
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['customer_account_create']
            ]
        );

        $attribute->save();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
        public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

If you want to add options to the dropdown you can use the follwing file
Vendor/Module/Model/Config/Source/Options.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\SourceInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class Options extends AbstractSource implements SourceInterface, OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            '' => __(''),
            1 => __('Option 1'),
            2 => __('Option 2'),
            3 => __('Option 3')
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $result = [];

        foreach (self::getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
            $result[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: how to show this field in the registration form and how to store the value that i get from this select field into a column that i have created

Comment: The field will be already shown in customer registration form as we have marked in the script.

'used_in_forms' => ['customer_account_create']

You will have to write some custom method to save this to a new custom column.

Comment: where and what code i have to write to get it in the customer_entity table